# Running Node, within another node instance

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

in my electron app, I have an index.html page. I have a .js file in which can only be run if you go into terminal and say "node index.js". My issue is when I link a button on the HTML page for the index.js, the script won't start. I need to find another way to initialize that node script to start.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 2):

The main process (see: [main vs renderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes)) in Electron has access to the full Node.js [API](https://nodejs.org/api/). You can have your button use the [`ipcRenderer`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) to send a message to the main process tellig it to run the file, which the main process responds to by either running the file directly (`require("the-file.js")`) or spawning a [child process running Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Npm start.

*OR*
you can always seperate your front and back-end and run only the back-end